# Uninstall removes installation folder as well as parent folder

Tags: wix, uninstallation

User selects Default Web Site to install his own site to subfolder under it.
All is ok, but on Uninstall step this folder+subfolder are deleted and naturally Default Web Site also is deleted from IIS.

How to avoid deleting of Default Web Site folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the WebSite element is outside of a Component it should be used as a locator only and not installed or uninstalled which sounds like what you want for Default Web Site.

If you have the WebSite element inside of a Component then you are telling WiX that you really do want to control the installation and uninstall of that WebSite.

[WiX WebSite Element (see bottom of page)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_website.htm)

Comment: may be my mistake: installer adds web app (virtual directory) to the existing Default Web Site. And uninstall removes virtual dir, user files AND this Default Web site(!) which was not created by installer but existed before..

Comment: +1. @Oleg, follow Rob's suggestion and move WebSite element out of the component definition. This is a proper solution to your case, as you install just the virtual dir, not the site itself. However, there are case when you need to put the site in the component even if it resolves to the Default Web Site. In this case, it makes sense to mark the component as 'Permanent'. But, just to emphasize once again, the solution to your case is 99% likely to move WebSite element out of the Component definition.

Answer (score 0):

An uninstall shouldn't leave resources on the target machine. This is why IIS elements are always removed by the uninstall process.

If you want to install your web site and leave it during uninstall, you can try using [custom actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead of WiX support.

Comment: I mean: IIS contains Default Web Site, installer adds user's Web app to this site. But Uninstall removes user's virtual directory+files and parent Default Web Site.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to have the wesite component inside a fragment not inside a component, the website would be searched not installled or uninstalled.

```
<!-- Because this is under a fragment (rather than a component) it merely locates the specified site rather than install or uninstall it -->
    <iis:WebSite Id="WS_DEFAULT" Description="Default Web Site">
      <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80" />
    </iis:WebSite>
```

So when uninstalling, only the app/files installed would be removed.